# Find word using reg exp

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

In a string  that includes numeric values like:

> 6.1, 6.1.1, 6.1.2.

I want to find (and replace)  the whole word `"6.1"` and ignore other words starting with `"6.1"`.  I tried using `\b` in my reg expression:

```
Dim OrginalString as String  = "Sample text with numeric values starting with 6.1 followed by 6.1.1, 6.1.2 "
Dim wordToFind as String = "6.1"
Dim pattern As String = [String].Format("\b({0})\b", wordToFind)
Dim ret As String = Regex.Replace(OrginalString, pattern, "1234",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

But it replaces all of the numeric "words" starting with `"6.1"`.  Here is the result:

```
ret = "Sample text with numeric values starting with 1234 followed by 1234.1, 1234.2 "
```

Solutions in VB or C# is OK with me.

It worked. :) Thank you Casimir et Hippolyte!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer worked for you, you should mark it as helpful (by clicking the up-arrow beside it) and/or correct (by clicking the check mark beside it).

Comment: Can't do this without knowing what `whole word` means. What delineates it from something you don't want to match?

Comment: You can't use the word boundary (\b) if you are redefining the meaning of word.

Comment: Are these comma delimited fields? If so, it should be `Dim pattern As String = [String].Format("(?<=,|^)({0})(?=,|$)", wordToFind)` anything else will eventually fail. Nevermind, read the rest.

Comment: Because your pattern contains regular expression characters, it is not doing what you expect.  It will happily match 6X1 because the dot will match any character.  If you might have regex characters in your pattern, you may need to escape them.  Alternatively, have you thought about String.Replace()?

Comment: @sln: The above string was a sample text. The actual string is a HTML File. The numeric values 6.1, 6.1.1 or 6.1.2 can be anywhere in the file. When I supply the value for 'wordToFind' say 6.1 , I want only that whole word in the HTML page to be replaced and ignore strings starting or containing 6.1 like it should ignore 6.1.1 , 3.6.1, 4.66.1.

Comment: @user3315245 - Ok, but it really doesn't explain anything. The fact is, you are trying to explain boundries around your string that overlap infinite combinations of characters regular expressions can match. You have to explicitly explain to yourself what `anywhere` means to you before you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
6\.1(?![.\d])
```

`(?!...)` means "not followed by" and is only a check, not a part of the match result.

Note: `\b` is only relative to the `\w` character class, since the `.` isn't in this class, there is a word boundary between `1` and `.2` in `6.1.2`

You can add a lookbehind to be sure that your number is preceded with a space or the start of the string, example:

```
(?<=^|\s)6\.1(?![.\d])
```

or not preceded with a number or a dot:

```
(?<![.\d])6\.1(?![.\d])
```

Comment: Yes you are right :( if I use 66.1 instead of 6.1 in the string the result is "Sample text with numeric values starting with 61234 followed by 6.1.1, 6.1.2". how to replace any numeric value like 6.1 or 66.1 or 666.1.1